# How to filter large array using Swift-2 for high performance

Tags: ios, arrays, multithreading, swift

I tried while typing in search-bar its results should be updates in table view, for that I'm filtering data dynamically while typing.

It works well when I tested in simulator, but actually running on iPhone, while typing it gives very slow response.

I know, due to large array i.e. array of 100000 records, due to this it might be giving me slow response.

This is my actual filtering stuff, in which when user start typing it will filter the data.

```
   func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
            {
                  self.filtered = self.data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in

                        let tmp: NSString = text
                        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: [NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch , NSStringCompareOptions.AnchoredSearch])
                    return range.location != NSNotFound

                })


                if(self.filtered.count == 0)
                {
                    self.searchActive = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    self.searchActive = true;
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                if(searchBar.text == "")
                {
                    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
                self.ContainerView.hidden=true
                self.tableView.hidden=false
                if(searchBar.text != "")
                {
                    self.ContainerView.hidden=true
                    self.tableView.hidden=false
                }
        }
```

How do I need to implement it, in such a way that it should filter it fast and provide fast response ?

Whether I should implement it with "multithreading" & how?

Even I tried this stuff using following methods...

dispatch_to_background_queue {} 
                & 
    func dispatch_to_main_queue(block: dispatch_block_t?) {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block!)
     }

Please suggest me proper solution for this.

Comment: any solution?..

Answer (score 0):

1. Previously sorted or filtered constraint array makes life very simpler.
2. Fetched data can be restricted by date its added, which can reduce number of data to be filtered

Also i believe this options are only a help or hint which is not necessarily needs to be strict, above can be slowly improved with respect to your feature.

Try using NSPredicate which is better to change i the course of improvement.

Comment: This is sorted array which I'm trying to filter as per user's input. Is there any different way to implement it.

Comment: Try using nspridicate and filter it with date (too many sources in stackOverflow), which may have to design the class with more parameters, which can be used one after the other if no data found in filter, if you are looking for only filter in string try dictionary search look for it in GeekforGeeks

Comment: Is it possible to use multithreading for this to enhance its filtering performance.

Comment: to my experience i believe this threads doesn't relate the problem you want to solve, so i am leaving it to you to explore when threads are required...